# WebIDE: How to Create Shell Plugin for Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

This is to:

- customize the Fiori Launchpad (e.g. modifying shell bar or adding footer)
- work in NEO environment (not Cloud Foundry)
- setup in WebIDE, not Business Application Studio

Other guides have pockets of outdated information such as the no-longer-existing option to create a 'Fiori Launchpad Plugin' from 'New Project from Template'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2020 Updated**

Steps:

- Create SAPUI5 template app
- Add following code to Component.js (& modify to your liking). Everything will be stored in Component.js, MVC will be left untouched. Everything in `.then()` add custom code for modifications to FLP.

```js
init: function () {
    // call the base component's init function
    UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    
    var rendererPromise= this._getRenderer();
    rendererPromise.then(function(oRenderer){
        // var bFull= jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("plugin-full");
        oRenderer.addHeaderItem("sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem", {
            icon:"sap-icon://add"
            ,tooltip:"Current Stage"
        },true,true);
    });
    
    // var oRenderer= sap.ushell.Container.getRenderer('fiori2');
    // oRenderer.addHeaderItem({icon:'sap-icon://add'},true,true);
    
    // enable routing
    // this.getRouter().initialize();
    // set the device model
    // this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
},
_getRenderer:function(){
    var that=this,
        oDeferred= new jQuery.Deferred(),
        oRenderer;
    that._oShellContainer= jQuery.sap.getObject("sap.ushell.Container");
    if(!that._oShellContainer){
        oDeferred.reject("Illegal state: shell container not available. This component must be executed in a unified shell runtime context.");
    } else{
        oRenderer= that._oShellContainer.getRenderer();
        if(oRenderer){oDeferred.resolve(oRenderer);}
        else{ //renderer not initialized yet, listen to rendererCreated event
            that._onRendererCreated= function(oEvent){
                oRenderer= oEvent.getParameter('renderer');
                if(oRenderer){oDeferred.resolve(oRenderer);}
                else{oDeferred.reject('Illegal state: shell renderer not available after receiving rendererLoaded event');}
            };
            that._oShellContainer.attachRendererCreatedEvent(that._onRendererCreated);
        }
    }
    return oDeferred.promise();
}
```

- Deploy your app
- Activate your plugin: Go to SCP's Portal service > Go to Service > Site Directory > *Choose a launchpad you want your plugin activated in > Content Management > Apps > *Add app ('+' icon)

1. Properties: *App Resource: select your deployed app > *App Type: select Shell Plugin
2. Catalogs: *select a Catalog to place your plugin in
3. Save

- Publish site using top ribbon's right side Globe icon

How it Looks: *Note the additional '+' button on top ribbon. Success!
[image]

References:

1. [Sample Plugin](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ushell/demoapps/UIPluginSampleAddHeaderItems/Component.js): this sample shows how to add header action items, footer, parameters, etc.
2. [Activating plugin](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8422cb487c2146999a2a7dab9cc85cf7/Cloud/en-US/87764543e31247b5b471c06e3f6da6fc.html): see ONLY the "Configuring a Shell Plugin App" section
3. API Reference on [what](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.Renderer) can be modified in FLP

Comment: In 2020 it should not use jQuery

Comment: @Marc this is more for reference to outdated guides. On another note, I'm getting the notion that jQuery is not ideal?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery in the _getRenderer function, this at least works for me in a quick test.
Uses Promises instead of Deferred and ObjectPath (requires "sap/base/util/ObjectPath") which is the recommended replacement for "$.sap.getObject" as this is deprecated.

```js
_getRenderer: function() {
    return new Promise(function(fnResolve, fnReject) {
        this._oShellContainer = ObjectPath.get("sap.ushell.Container");
        if (!this._oShellContainer) {
            fnReject(
                "Illegal state: shell container not available; this component must be executed in a unified shell runtime context."
            );
        } else {
            var oRenderer = this._oShellContainer.getRenderer();
            if (oRenderer) {
                fnResolve(oRenderer);
            } else {
                // renderer not initialized yet, listen to rendererCreated event
                this._onRendererCreated = function(oEvent) {
                    oRenderer = oEvent.getParameter("renderer");
                    if (oRenderer) {
                        fnResolve(oRenderer);
                    } else {
                        fnReject(
                            "Illegal state: shell renderer not available after receiving 'rendererLoaded' event."
                        );
                    }
                };
                this._oShellContainer.attachRendererCreatedEvent(
                    this._onRendererCreated
                );
            }
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```